# I have a bunch of images with varying sizes. How do I re-size them while maintaining proportions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pixel, counter

This is a bit more tricky than it sounds so let me try my best to explain.

I am specifically working with images of clothing from sites like HM and Net-a-porter. I would like to add these images to my website, stacking them vertically so that they create an outfit.

I need to re-size the shirt so that it proportionally sits on top of the jeans. The dimensions of the jeans are fixed at 100px width by 250px length. When I resize the shirt to the same width it (100px) it SOMETIMES matches. Using a different shirt (perhaps one with longer sleeves, no sleeves, etc) will result in mixed results and will not match the 100px width waistline of the jeans.

When saved these pics contain a certain amount of white space within the jpeg that varies from image to image. I have tried resizing with and without the white space (by cropping it down to the edges of the item) but this did not help either.

This is all supposed to be an automated process (like using the clipper tool on Pinterest of Polyvore) therefore non of the above can be done through photoshop or by hand, which makes it all the more difficult.

A screenshot of my problem can be found here:

[image]

I have also researched pixel counter scripts and have wondered if resizing  can be done by counting the pixel width of the waistline of the clothing item (excluding all white pixel data) ??

I feel like I'm reaching into that particular are of "it cant be done, too many variables" and would love for someone to at least point me in the right direction. Thanks alot!

Comment: To automate something like this (discerning the width so multiple images can be automatically scaled to match widths) would take some image analysis that could identify the max width of the core subject.  If the background is always as clean as what you have in your examples and always white or transparent, it's probably as straightforward an algorithm as just going row by row through the image and counting the row with max width of non-background color.

Comment: Are you trying to do this server-side or in browser javascript?

Comment: as you are displaying some sort of cloth ,i recommend do it using any image editor rather than code.

Comment: So you want to not only resize the picture but also crop the white spaces, as I understand, but... are all image backgrounds white? The proportions of a shirt will be different from a sleeveless shirt (as your example), a longer shirt or even a top, right?

Comment: Although I think the solution you are after is going to take a heck of a lot of processing, and produce a lot of bad matches...You could tweak you presentation a bit, the human mind has great ability to make up the missing bits. You example image is not too bad...perhaps if the trousers(US:pants) were always longer than the top...it would be clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS `max-width` and `max-height` to set the proportions.  That will scale everything appropriately.

For example:

`img { max-width: 100px; }`

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KSzhS/

It isn't too difficult to do.

Here's a function that I wrote for doing "basically" the same thing, but instead of analyzing clothing, it's analyzing letters.  It's written in PHP, but if you can use HTML5, you can do it on the client-side too.

```
/**
* Function: Returns the space between letters, and the width of letters.
*           The first index is set to 0, as that is where it starts
*           Since spaces don't register (no pixels), strlen may not work.
* $image image cursor (from imagecreatetruecolor)
*/
function get_letter_dimensions($image)
{
   $bg           = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
   $height       = imagesy($image) - 1; // was causing issues without
   $width        = imagesx($image);
   $bottom       = 0;
   $right        = 0;
   $letter_space = array(0=>0); // This holds the pixels between the letters
   $letter_width = array(0=>0); // This holds the width of the letters
   $y            = $height;
   $spacing      = 0;
   $lettering    = 0;
   $data         = array();

   for ($x = 0 ; $x < $width ; $x++) 
   {
      while((imagecolorat($image, $x, $y) == $bg) && ($y >= 1 )) $y--;

      if($y == 0) 
      {
         if($lettering) $letter_width[] = $lettering;
         $lettering = 0;
         $spacing++;
      }
      else
      {
         if($spacing) $letter_space[] = $spacing;
         $spacing = 0;
         $lettering++;
      }
      $y = $height;
   }

   foreach($letter_space as $k=>$val) $data[$k] = $val + $letter_width[$k];

   return $data;      
}
```

You're going to need to modify that though, so that it doesn't pull in for letters, but you'd start at the beginning, and when you hit a non-clear or white pixel, you'd mark it, and start at the end.  Then you'll have your points of reference.

It's just some simple maths, and clothing analysis.  If you're interested in having the "waist-lines" match up, you'll probably want to start at the bottom, and go up, for the images of the shirts.  Then you can see where a "line" of pixels are, which would represent where the waist is.  And base your calculations off of that.

So, if you want to help yourself out, start `echo`ing the results from the function provided, so that you can see what it looks like

### Example

```
------------------------------
------------------------------
------------------------------
------------------------------
-------**-------------**------
------*--*-----------*--*-----
-----*-------------------*----
------------------------------
----------***********---------
--***---------------------***-
------------------------------
```

That's if you're going from bottom to top, and you can "see", where the waist line is.  Then count pixels, and resize from that.  You can modify this function to make another auto-cropping function.  Also, if you want, modify this function so you can start from the top, or go horizontal and start from either side.  You can even get crazy and allow offsets to be used.

Once you have that type of information set up, you can really start to find out what you're working with.  If you're dealing with images where the pixel at 0,0 will NEVER be used, you can try to use that as the background color.  That'll help with the auto-cropping functionality.

The more points of measurement you make, the more intelligent you can make your analysis.  And if you have access to information about what you're looking at, for example, you have the images associated with other data, then you can take some short-cuts (so you won't have to do a bunch of analysis to know if you're working with "Pants", "Skirts", "Shirts" and "Dresses").

### Edit: Additional Thoughts

Just thought about this a bit more... This is actually a pretty neat little thing that you're doing, and I'm thinking about writing my own version of it for fun.  Here's some stuff that I've been thinking about.  The implementation of how you're pulling in these images in, is important.

- Are you pulling all the data from a directory?
- Do you have the images already set up different so that you're aware of what you're pulling in?
- Do you know what image is a shirt, and what image is a pair of pants?

You can also set up a "vetting process", where you would store the offsets on the original image that gets scaled.  This would allow for you to bypass calculations, and instead just look-up the stored data.  Anyway, the "vetting process" would allow for you to double-check  that the calculations are set, and then store them.

I don't know.  I'll let you know if I do something like this though.

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, you have deff. pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: I just saw your additional thoughts :) As images are collected online they would be assigned specific tags, ie pants, red, shirt, blue, pac sun, etc. So yes, it would be known exactly what sort of article of clothing is being displayed and as such there would be certain rules as to how it is displayed.

Comment: The images that are being displayed would be pulled from a database where they are stored. I'm not sure what you mean by your second question regarding images already being set up.

Comment: @user1762433 For the second question, I meant, were you dealing with sanitized data (images that you KNEW were what they were supposed to be), or were they being pulled in from a third-party source.

Comment: they would be pulled from a third party source. After gathering images from a variety of sources they all contain white pixel data around the actual clothing item. This amount of white pixel space of course varies from site to site

Comment: Tim, I would like to contact you personally in regards to this project. Please email me your info at simaslucascastillo@gmail.com. Thank you!

Comment: @user1762433 I emailed you a while ago, but never got a response back.  Please let me know if you're still interested.

Answer (score 0):

use the width attribute of the image without the height..it resize the image maintaining the aspect ratio. example:

```
<img src="yourpic.jpg" width="100px">
```

dont include height attribute as it will change it's height outside from it's aspect ratio. just change that value of width until it matches to your desired size. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the images doesn't help to reduce the size of the image and yes the image can view somewhat with blur effect when it is reduced to its original size.

First make your requirement clear that
1)why you want to resize the images? depending on your requirement the solution will be different.
2) if you want to resize the image to its proportion, then you will required Photoshop tool to the size you required which will reduce the image size and maintain sharpness.
3) if you want to just resize the image by keeping original proportion, then pls read my first statement.

Hope this will clear the usage of images.